# iOS: dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier returning cell with IBOutlets that are nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom UITableViewCell with one view defined in a XIB file:

```
@interface MetroTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *metroLineName;
@end
```

I am dequeuing the cell as such:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    MetroTableViewCell *cell = (MetroTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MetroTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // AT THIS POINT, cell.metroLineName is equal to nil
    return cell;
}
```

The class is being registered with the table view:

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[MetroTableViewCell class]
       forCellReuseIdentifier:@"MetroTableViewCell"];
```

In the XIB file, I am also setting the class to "MetroTableViewCell"

So why is the IBOutlet set to nil?

NOTE: This problem does NOT occur when I use:

```
MetroTableViewCell *cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MetroTableViewCell"
                                                              owner:self options:nil]
                                                      objectAtIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you create a xib show you need `registerNib` not class. If you create custom cell with no `xib`, you will use `registerClass`.

So you should change this code:

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[MetroTableViewCell class]
   forCellReuseIdentifier:@"MetroTableViewCell"];
```

To:

```
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"MetroTableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"MetroTableViewCell"];
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 1):

Using `registerClass:forReuseIdentifier:` doesn't use a NIB to create the cell. It simply creates a new instance of the given class.

You want to use `registerNib:forReuseIdentifier:`

Instead of this:

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[MetroTableViewCell class]
   forCellReuseIdentifier:@"MetroTableViewCell"];
```

use:

```
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"MetroTableViewCell" bundle: nil]
   forCellReuseIdentifier:@"MetroTableViewCell"];
```